# Readability of the decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have a problem with the decision tree. It is not very clear.

The structure of my data is as follows:

```
> str(mi)
'data.frame':   4393 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ OS_Gatunek       : Factor w/ 5 levels "Taraxacum ancistrolobum",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PH_CreateDate    : Factor w/ 15 levels "2016-04-06","2016-04-19",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ L_Dl             : num  7.91 8.96 10.18 10.09 9.4 ...
 $ L_SzerMaksOs     : num  1.93 3.98 3.12 4.04 2.75 2.69 3.69 3.23 2.3 2.49 ...
 $ L_DlMax          : num  3.51 4.08 5.58 5.04 3.99 3.6 5.65 4.62 3.33 4.18 ...
 $ KS_DlSk_Sr       : num  1.78 3.28 2.88 4.19 1.88 2.47 3.11 4.04 1.61 2.09 ...
 $ KS_Dl_Sr         : num  1.68 2.83 2.62 3.84 1.68 2.12 2.87 3.8 1.44 1.86 ...
 $ KS_Sz            : num  1.35 3.41 2.38 3.31 1.66 2.35 2.45 2.96 1.57 1.9 ...
 $ KB_DlSkos_Sr     : num  1.07 1.94 1.84 1.69 1.25 1.49 1.96 1.77 1.43 1.55 ...
 $ KB_Dl_Sr         : num  0.62 1.49 1.12 1.34 0.86 0.77 1.22 1.07 0.82 1.05 ...
 $ KB_Szer_Sr       : num  0.85 1.23 1.46 0.94 0.89 1.32 1.53 1.41 1.17 1.14 ...
 $ KB_SzerPierwKlapy: num  1.75 3.99 2.9 4.1 2.34 2.75 3.11 3.39 1.96 2.46 ...
 $ I_Dl_Sr          : num  0.25 0.86 0.48 0.61 0.44 0.41 0.7 0.86 0.14 0.59 ...
 $ I_SzOs           : num  0.37 0.83 0.47 0.87 0.39 0.73 0.53 0.96 0.4 0.33 ...
 $ I_DlSz_Sr        : num  2.3 4.08 3.35 5.23 2.34 3.39 3.22 4.43 1.96 2.55 ...
 $ O_Dl_Sr          : num  0.67 0.75 2.02 0.85 0.74 1.4 1.07 0.26 0.6 0.96 ...
 $ O_SzerOs         : num  1.35 1.59 1.31 0.91 1.08 0.94 1.18 0.84 1.71 0.93 ...
 $ O_SzerOskrz_Sr   : num  0.55 0.65 0.48 0.34 0.39 0.31 0.49 0.29 0.74 0.27 ...
```

The code looks like this:

```
model<-rpart(mi[,1]~., data=mi[,-c(1,2)])
plot(model)
text(model, cex=0.5)
```

And tree like this:

[image: Decision tree made from a plot()]

If I use the fancyRpartPlot() command from "rattle" package:

```
fancyRpartPlot(model, sub=NULL)
```

The tree is like this:

[image: Decision tree made from a fancyRpartPlot()]

And if I use the rpart.plot() from "rpart.plot" package:

```
rpart.plot(model)
```

The tree looks like this:

[image: Decision tree made from a rpart.plot()]

They are completely illegible.

Despite the variety of literature available on the internet, I found nothing that would improve the legibility of my tree.

What should I change? I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: The only thing I managed to do was to insert shortcuts instead of full species names, reduce the font and slightly change the margins: `plot(model, uniform=TRUE, margin=0.2)` `text(model, cex=.7)` It does not look very beautiful, but it was better than it was.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `rpart.plot`, create extra space for bigger text in the plotted tree, by using `fallen.leaves=FALSE` and/or `tweak=1.1` (say).

Also reduce the length of the variable and factor names by using `varlen=4` and `faclen=4` (say).

See also the suggestions in the FAQ chapter of the [rpart.plot vignette](http://www.milbo.org/doc/prp.pdf).